# Disposing Single element in c#

Tags: c#, dispose

I have a Windows Form application that use a Notifier for capture SQLDependency change event with Entity Framework and all works fine. The EntityChangeNotifier is a project that elaborate the SQLDependency.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private readonly EntityChangeNotifier<SpRicezioneSpedizioniLightNotifier, GemapDbContext> _entityChangeNotifier;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        _entityChangeNotifier = StartNotifier();
    }

    private EntityChangeNotifier<SpRicezioneSpedizioniLightNotifier, GemapDbContext> StartNotifier()
    {
        var notifer = new EntityChangeNotifier<SpRicezioneSpedizioniLightNotifier, GemapDbContext>(
        p => p.SPEDIZIONE_STATO_GENERAZIONE == "I" || p.SPEDIZIONE_STATO_GENERAZIONE == "U");
        notifer.Error += (sender, e) => { /*log*/ };
        notifer.Changed += (sender, e) => { /*action when chagned*/};
        return notifer;
    }

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing && (components != null))
        {
            components.Dispose();
            _entityChangeNotifier.Dispose();
        }
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }
}
```

How can i dispose the only notifier and reactivate a new notifier if I have an error?I want to restart the notifier automatically if i have same error in the listen.

Comment: Hard to guess why this is a problem.  I suppose you don't actually like the *readonly* keyword.  Your Dispose() method has a bug, it should still be disposed if components == null.

Comment: Sorry but i don't know how to write what i want in my code. Where i want to dispose the notifier i dispose all the windows form application